# react-chartjs gives back a type error : (intermediate value)[chartType] is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-chartjs

when i run the server..this component is loaded ...no errors found on server side...but browser console gives back a following error :

**Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)[chartType] is not a function**

my code is as follows :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var chart = require('chart.js');
var DoughnutChart = require("react-chartjs").Doughnut;
var Tempvshum = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var chartOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke : true
  };
var chartData = [{
    value: 300,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
  }];
   return(<DoughnutChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} />);
   }
  });
module.exports = Tempvshum;
```

Comment: I am working on a react-chartjs component right now as well and am receiving this same error....I've confirmed that both react-chart and its dependency chart.js are loaded, and have tried different versions as well. Does anyone have any idea?

`var chart = new Chart(ctx)[chartType](nextProps.data, nextProps.options || {});`

Seems that this is the line that is causing the problem from react-chart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is related to chart.js.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js says that the package has been uploaded 2 days ago and it is now in version 2.0.0-beta2. I modified my package.json to use the older version 1.1.1 and everything works.

Comment: interesting, i'll try that. This could be related to the recent release of React 15.0.1, 4/8/2016 according to `npm view react@15.0.1 time`

Comment: I was also experiencing this issue and when I went back down to 1.1.1 everything was fine. Currently `react-chartjs` does not support `chartjs` v 2.0, but there is an active branch for v2.0 development that will be merged when ready: https://github.com/jhudson8/react-chartjs/tree/chartjs-v2

Comment: https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2 This will save you lots of hair pulling hours.